# Delete branches in SVN based on age

Tags: svn

How can I delete multiple branches all at once based on age of the branch? I have some 500 old branches which I want to delete. I can't imagine doing this one by one.

By the way, I use svn on CentOS6 and I can view it using sventon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
svn help rm
...
usage: ...
       2. delete URL...

  2. Each item specified by a URL is deleted from the repository
    via an immediate commit.

Valid options:
  ...
  --targets ARG            : pass contents of file ARG as additional args
```

Prepare list of branches to delete, write to file, use it with --targets